# PHP session changing on each request only on HTTP. Cookie not setting

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am working on a project where a customer will get their own template website. They will get their own free subdomain, this will be http by default an example is below.

http://www.jess-jewels.mytreatments.co.uk/info.php
https://www.jess-jewels.mytreatments.co.uk/info.php

On the secure link you will see the cookie PHPSESSID is set correctly and the session id remains throughout and does not change.

On the non secure link this changes on page load and no PHPSESSID cookie is being set in the browser, unsure why.

PHP Session info here:

````
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary wddx
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  32  32
session.gc_divisor  0   0
session.gc_maxlifetime  2880    2880
session.gc_probability  0   0
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.lazy_write  On  On
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70   /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0```
````

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working by overwrite the cookie:

```
session_start();
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie("PHPSESSID", session_id(), 0, $params["path"], $params["domain"],
    false,  // this is the secure flag you need to set. Default is false.
    true  // this is the httpOnly flag you need to set
);
```